# return last non-null value in left join

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that goes like this

```
select
  a.date_field,
  b.date_field,
  b.interested_data
from tbl_dates a
  left join tbl_data b
     on a.date_field = b.date_field
```

this gives me a resultset like:

```
a_date_field | b_date_field | b_interested_data
2022-01-01   | 2022-01-01   | data_1
2022-01-02   | 2022-01-02   | data_2
2022-01-03   | null         | null
```

is it possible to return the last non-null value for b_date_field and b_interested_data in row 3? Ideally the result should be

```
a_date_field | b_date_field | b_interested_data
2022-01-01   | 2022-01-01   | data_1
2022-01-02   | 2022-01-02   | data_2
2022-01-03   | 2022-01-02   | data_2
```

I know that b_date_field would seem like an error but I am only interested in b_interested_data.

Comment: Is your presentation tier looping through the rows and displaying them one at a time? If so, couldn’t the presentation tier keep track of the last value it saw, and use that when it encounters a null? This seems like the right place to do it.

Comment: (Yes, you can do it in T-SQL, but this is a presentation problem better solved at presentation  time IMHO.)

Comment: no. this is just using ssms or azure data studio. I would prefer that the query is run in some sql browser tool and not in code.

Comment: This is going to be in T-SQL. I am going to put this query in a stored procedure that is used to populate a table on schedule.

Comment: Rows in a resultset have no defined order if the query that created it has no ORDER BY clause. If row matters - and "last" implies it does - then the query MUST have an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: could there be more than one null data point and all such null values need to revert to the "last" populated values based on the a_date_field?

Comment: yes, there can be more than one null data point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I realized from your answers that the join condition can also be `>=` or `<=` and not only `=`. This is the solution I came up with:

```
drop table if exists #dates;
select
    *
into #dates
from (values (1,cast('20220101' as date)),(2,cast('20220102' as date)),(3,cast('20220103' as date))) a(date_id,[date])
;


drop table if exists #data;
select
    *
into #data
from (values ('data_1',cast('20220101' as date)),('data_2',cast('20220102' as date))) b(interested_data,[date])
;


select 
    ab.a_date,
    ab.b_date,
    ab.interested_data
from (
    select
        a.date a_date,
        b.date b_date,
        b.interested_data,
        row_number() over (
            partition by
                a.date
            order by
                a.date,
                b.date desc
        ) rn
    from #dates a
        left join #data b
            on a.date >= b.date
) ab
where
    ab.rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically I think there are two approaches. One is to use apply, one is to use last_value. I have prepared a small insert with two selects that return the same table, so pick the one you like most (EDIT: Pick the one that fits your solution and has the best performance in your case).

```
select
    *
into #dates
from (values (1,cast('20220101' as date)),(2,cast('20220102' as date)),(3,cast('20220103' as date))) a(date_id,[date])
;

select
    *
into #data
from (values ('data_1',cast('20220101' as date)),('data_2',cast('20220102' as date))) b(interested_data,[date])
;

--Solution 1
select distinct
      last_value(a.date) over (partition by a.date order by b.date rows between current row and unbounded following)
    , last_value(b.date) over (partition by a.date order by b.date rows between current row and unbounded following)
    , last_value(b.interested_data) over (partition by a.date order by b.date rows between current row and unbounded following)
from #dates a
left join #data b on
    b.date <= a.date
;

--Solution 2
select
    a.date
    , sub.date as b_date
    , sub.interested_data
from #dates a
outer apply (
    select top 1
          b.date as date
        , b.interested_data as interested_data
    from #data b
    where b.date <= a.date
    order by b.date desc
) as sub
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can do it using a `APPLY` operator. Get the "last" row from table b based on `date_field`

```
select
  a.date_field,
  b.date_field,
  b.interested_data
from tbl_dates a
  cross apply
  (
      select TOP (1) b.date_field, b.interested_data
      from  tbl_data b
      where a.date_field >= b.date_field
      order by b.date_field desc
  ) b
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lag()` and `coalese()` we can do it:  assuming a_date_Field is the order we can use to determine the "Prior" value.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT '2022-01-01' a_date_field, '2022-01-01' b_date_field, 'data_1' b_interested_data UNION ALL
SELECT '2022-01-02',   '2022-01-02',   'data_2' UNION ALL
SELECT '2022-01-03',    null,          null)
SELECT a_date_Field, 
       coalesce(B_Date_Field,lag(B_date_Field) over (order by a_date_Field)), 
       coalesce(B_Interested_Data,lag(B_Interested_Data) over (order by a_date_Field)) FROM CTE
```

Giving us:

```
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| a_date_Field | (No column name) | (No column name) |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
| 2022-01-01   | 2022-01-01       | data_1           |
| 2022-01-02   | 2022-01-02       | data_2           |
| 2022-01-03   | 2022-01-02       | data_2           |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: This solution will only work if a maximum of one day is empty. If you have the case where 30 days of data might be empty, you'd have to account for that by using 30 different lag() scenarios.

Comment: True.  It's how I interpreted the question.  Didn't expect/consider multiples null value records.